# mhddfs not support single file to split multiple hard drives.. if file size exceed limit of single storage device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, virtual-directory, big-data

I'm using mhddfs to combine multiple drives that are mounted over network using NFS.

e.g. There are three machines

```
Server Name  Dir    Space
Server 1     /home  10 GB Space
Server 2     /home  10 GB Space
Server 3     /home  10 GB Space
```

Using NFS i mounted the following:

```
Server 1 /home to Server 3 /home/mount1
Server 2 /home to Server 3 /home/mount3
```

Then using mhddfs i merge or unified mount1 and mount 2 e.g.

```
mhddfs /home/server/mount1,/home/server/mount2 /home/server/mount
```

Now i have 30 GB space altogether. but when i tried to write the file in mount directory that has more than 10 GB space it fails...

It seems mhddfs can't split large file e.g. 20 GB file.. so that it can store

Please give an idea, that how i can achive this e.e AUFS, UNIFOS etc........

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a limitation of mhddfs, it looks like files must fit onto one of the participating devices (minus the free space threshold)

> If an overflow arises while writing  to  the  hdd1  then  a  file
>   content already written will be transferred to a  hdd  containing
>   enough of free space for a file.

The only real  solution to your problem is to buy storage to meet your requirements.

Comment: can i solve this problem by other soliutions AUFS, UNIFOS or mdadm...As my file size is 16TB... and there is no such storage device..

Comment: @Imran There are plenty of companies that can supply storage to meet that file size depending on your availability and speed requirements it could get a bit spendy.